# PHP: setcookie() and unset() not deleting the cookie

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, unset

Ok, so i got a pretty standard cookie setup. I set the cookie on some event and save some garbage in it. On a specific $_GET call i want to completely delete it, which i try to achieve with a combination of **`unset()`** and **`setcookie()`**. I wrote a specific function for that use called **`delCookie()`**.

Now the weird thing is: if i call the **`delCookie()`** over a **`$_GET`** variable which i catch with an if clause, the cookie vanishes as expected. ( I do not access the cookie before it gets deleted here.)

BUT

if I call **`delCookie()`** AFTER i wrote the cookies contents to a **`sqlite3`** database, ( I access the cookie) it wont get deleted.

any ideas why? and any solution ideas which do not require me to keep the delete signal to a point where the page gets reloaded without accessing the cookie? (or is this even a bug?)

#

relevant code (not in order):

```
119     /**
120      * @brief 'Deletes' the cookie 'bought'. It basically sets its expiration date to 1 hour in the past, so the browser w    ill collect it.
121      */
122     function delCookie() {
123         global $cookieDel;
124         echo "eating ...<br />";
125         unset($_COOKIE['bought']);
126         if(!setcookie('bought', FALSE, time()-3600)) {
127             echo "Error 2";
128         } else {
129             $cookieDel = TRUE;
130         }
131     }


132    /**
133      * @brief Writes a purchase to the database 'bought.db' in the    following order:TIME:DATE | ITEMS(separated by a ',') |     NAME(of the buyer) | TOTAL(amount of money spent). [consider writing the store brand aswell?]
134      */
135     function toDatabase($items, $amount) {
136         $database = new SQLite3('bought.db');
137         $fixString = preg_replace('/<br \/>/', ', ', $items);
138 
139         $SQLret = $database->query('INSERT INTO bought(date, items, name, total) VALUES("'.date('y/m/d_H:m').'", "'.$fixString.'", "test", '.$amount.');');
140     }
```

Comment: What does the delCookie() function look like? Also, can you post the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: do you have any output to the browser between writing to db and calling delCookie()? That could be the reason.

Comment: yes, but I am not accessing the cookie. (and removing that output does not fix it)

Comment: yeah, but removing the echo does not fix it, the cookie is still there after a page reload.

Comment: did you also remove the `echo` in `delCookie()` ?

Comment: yes, both the ***eating ... <br />*** and the ***Error 2***.

Comment: I then can't find anything else that might be wrong in your presented code. Did you get the `"Error 2"` at all?

Answer (score 3):

Using `unset()` on a value in `$_COOKIE` does *not* delete it. It just removes it from the `$_COOKIE` superglobal but the cookie still exists on the user's machine. To actually delete a cookie you need to set a cookie with the same name and set the expires date in the past. And then you still have to wait until *after* the HTTP headers for the page sent as it is up to the browser to actually delete the cookie. Then on the next page request the cookie will be present in the request headers. Only then you can check if the cookie is actually deleted.

Comment: So why does `isset($_COOKIE['bought'])` evaluate to **true** even though i did an `unset($_COOKIE['bought'])` before it?

Comment: ^ without reloading the page of course.

But as you can see in the function `delCookie()` I set the cookies expiration date to 1 hour in the past and send it back to the client where it should get deleted. Now if i do not access the cookie serverside before deleting it, it gets deleted client side as expected. BUT if id access the cookies values server side before setting the expiration date inot the past, it does not get deleted. why?